# Arranging desktop icons with C#

Tags: c#, winapi

Alright guys, so here is what I am trying to achieve:

I want all the disordered desktop icons to arrange themselves towards the top-left of the desktop on a button click.

Here is the code I am using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]

private static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint wParam, int lParam);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr hwnd = GetDesktopWindow(); //hwnd for desktop
    SendMessage(hwnd, LVM_ARRANGE, LVA_ALIGNLEFT, 0);   
}
```

I believe there are unassigned integers associated with `LVM_ARRANGE` and `LVA_ALIGNLEFT`, can anyone please guide me what they are. I am unfamiliar with using dlls, so pardon me if I am asking a stupid question.

Thanks!

**Help me guys, I am using the following code and its still not working:**

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        IntPtr hanle = GetHandle();
        IntPtr done;
        done = SendMessage(hanle, LVM_ARRANGE, LVA_ALIGNLEFT, IntPtr.Zero);

    }

    public IntPtr GetHandle()
    {
        hShellWnd = GetShellWindow();
        hDefView = FindWindowEx(hShellWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", null);
        folderView = FindWindowEx(hDefView, IntPtr.Zero,"SysListView32", null);
        return folderView;
    }


    public const int LVM_FIRST =  0x1000;
    public const uint LVM_ARRANGE = LVM_FIRST + 22; 
    //public const IntPtr LVA_SNAPTOGRID = 5;

     IntPtr LVA_ALIGNLEFT = new IntPtr(0x0001);

     IntPtr hShellWnd;
     IntPtr hDefView;
     IntPtr folderView;


    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
```

Comment: by item i mean icon...

Comment: You might check http://source.winehq.org/source/include/commctrl.h for the values of the LVM_* and LVA_* symbols (i hope you have basic C reading skills, since the link leads you to a header file. You should also be able to find the commctrl.h file in the platform SDK installed together with VS...)

Comment: User the documented interface: [SetCurrentFolderFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775546(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: -1 Raymond already told you how to do it

Comment: can you please elaborate...

Comment: You'll find a solution here: [Manipulating the positions of desktop icons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933). The article is about a different topic but mentions how to modify the folder flags of the desktop in passing.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and this sample seemed to work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
SendMessage(GetDesktopWindow(), LVM_ARRANGE, LVA_SNAPTOGRID , 0);
}


public const int LVM_ARRANGE = 4118;
public const int LVA_SNAPTOGRID = 5;


[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern int SendMessage( IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam );
```

It came from the following link: http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/1168661/Auto-Arrange-desktop-icons.aspx

Note that from the header file

```
#define LVA_DEFAULT             0x0000
#define LVA_ALIGNLEFT           0x0001
#define LVA_ALIGNTOP            0x0002
#define LVA_SNAPTOGRID          0x0005
```

Therefore to align left you want to use the int 1.

Comment: This was never documented to work and stopped working a while ago.