# How do I arrange or sort the desktop icons in c#?

Tags: c#, sorting, icons, desktop, sendmessage

You know when you right-click the desktop and there's a "Sort by" option that allows you to sort the icons by "Name", "Size", "Item Type", or "Date Modified"? Well, I want to find a way to sort the desktop's icons with a push of a button.

I saw a similar question being asked here on stackoverflow but it's old and the code didn't work for me. The link to the question is: [Arranging desktop icons with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965672/arranging-desktop-icons-with-c-sharp) . I'm trying to achieve this in Windows 10.

There was a comment on there that said that the LVM_* and LVA_* values are stored in the  commctrl.h file which comes with the SDK. I couldn't find that file for some reason.

Here's what i'm using:

```
  //sort desktop
     public const int LVM_ARRANGE = 4118;
     public const int LVM_ALIGNLEFT = 1;


     [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
     public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow(); 


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

     //end of sort desktop 

private void organizeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var DesktopHandle = GetDesktopWindow();
       MessageBox.Show(GetDesktopWindow().ToString());

       SendMessage(GetDesktopWindow(), LVM_ARRANGE, LVM_ALIGNLEFT, 0);

   }
```

I've been digging for info or some sort of direction about this topic, especially regarding windows 10, but I can't find much.  Please help?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, the desktop (not tile world!) is still a SysListView32, but the `GetDesktopWindow` API call will return the handle of its grandparent, a Progman window - reminiscence of the ancient "Program Manager" of Windows 3.0. Then there is a shim of the SHELLDLL_DefView class, and below that you find buried the listview you're after.

Use [the information from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5691808/1132334) to move down from the shell window to the folder view, which you can eventually send the LVM_ARRANGE message.

This is a brittle approach, as it relies on undocumented properties of the operating system, which may change at any time with updates or new versions. It will probably break also when a user uses a slideshow as desktop background, because Windows then rearranges the desktop window stack. Hack to deal with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36566823/1132334).

Another approach which is documented and less likely to break in future versions, with the downside of involving COM and a nightmare from C#, is via the `IFolderView` of shell automation, two relevant finds [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393/).

Comment: Wow. You're fast! Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question, I appreciate it. I read the post you linked to in your response. What i got out of it is that if i create code that interacts with the actual desktop, then it is bound to break due to future updates just as you said. That Microsoft didn't intend for developers to interact with the actual desktop in this way and its unreliable. I wanted to get scattered icons on the desktop to be aligned neatly on the left. The other solution I have in mind is moving all of the icons to a different folder and then back. lol. your thoughts?

Comment: if its just for fun or just for your own learning and entertainment, then go ahead. I would not include it in a commercial application that I'd attempt to get certified and published. I think the idea of moving files out of the desktop folder and back again is ingenious. But consider the role of desktop.ini in that. Again, if you do that on your own PC no problem, if a commercial program would do that on mine I'd kick it out.

Comment: yeah..its for a small desktop program/tool I intend to sell for a bit of money. Damn. :( This is the last feature, which i'm having trouble with. I'll read the other posts you linked to. Thanks for the help.