# Getting the list-view control handle from an IShellView instance

Tags: windows, winapi

For what I understand File Explorer uses a list-view control to display the files. (For example [How do I arrange or sort the desktop icons in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390489/how-do-i-arrange-or-sort-the-desktop-icons-in-c/48390605)).

If I have an object that implements `IShellView` is it possible to get the window handle that could be used with LVM messages? LVM messages like these https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/bumper-list-view-control-reference-messages require handle of type [`HWND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg/windows-data-types) to be sent messages to.

Comment: This would rely on specific implementation details. Can't you use the shell API to achieve your goal?

Comment: ask for [`IFolderView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifolderview) from your `IShellView` interface. anyway `IShellView::GetWindow` can be used

Comment: the `IShellView::GetWindow` return `SHELLDLL_DefView` class window, it child can be `DirectUIHWND` not `SysListView32`

Comment: File Explorer stopped using a ListView control back in Windows 7, I believe. It certainly hasn't used one for a long time, except in one place (the desktop).

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. It doesnt make sense for me to use this then. I was looking for a less expensive alternative to IShellWindow::Refresh to force File Explorer to resort files.

Comment: Always best to ask about the actual problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Raymond Chen explained in his comment ListView is not used anymore except on the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

The following function found on the net re-classes DirectUIHWND control into the familiar SysListView32. However the change is not propagated until you double-click on the list-view items, manually change directories.

Be aware that every time you go to a different directory then the list-view presented for that directory has a different handle, which makes the task of sub-classing the control a kind of 'challenging'.

I still have to figure how to restore the list-view with the following function and refreshing without having to use mouse double-clicks.

```cpp
void RevertExplorerToListView(HWND explorerHandle)
{
    IShellWindows* shellWindow;

    if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IShellWindows,
        reinterpret_cast<void**>(&shellWindow))))
    {
        VARIANT v;
        V_VT(&v) = VT_I4;
        IDispatch* dispatch;
        BOOL found = FALSE;

        for (V_I4(&v) = 0; !found && shellWindow->Item(v, &dispatch) == S_OK; V_I4(&v)++)
        {
            IWebBrowserApp* browserApp;

            if (SUCCEEDED
            (dispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowserApp, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&browserApp))))
            {
                HWND appHandle;
                
                if(SUCCEEDED
                (browserApp->get_HWND(reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR*>(&appHandle))) && appHandle == explorerHandle)
                {
                    found = TRUE;
                    IServiceProvider* provider;

                    if (
                        SUCCEEDED(browserApp->QueryInterface(IID_IServiceProvider, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&provider))))
                    {
                        IShellBrowser* browser;

                        if (
                            SUCCEEDED(provider->QueryService(SID_STopLevelBrowser, IID_IShellBrowser, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&browser))))
                        {
                            IFolderViewOptions* options;
                            if (SUCCEEDED(browser->QueryInterface(IID_IFolderViewOptions,
                                reinterpret_cast<void**>(&options))))
                            {
                                if (FAILED(options->SetFolderViewOptions(FVO_VISTALAYOUT, FVO_VISTALAYOUT)))
                                {
                                }
                                options->Release();
                            }
                            browser->Release();
                        }
                        provider->Release();
                    }
                }
                browserApp->Release();
            }
        }
        shellWindow->Release();
    }
}
```